# How can I generate random numbers without duplicates using Math.random()?

Tags: java, random

I am working on a program that will simulte a simplified version of Blackjack. Whenever someone draws a card, it can't be reused. Up to this point, I have learned about the Math.Random() function, so I am positive that I am supposed to use it in this assignment.

My first attempt was to create a boolean array of 52 (52 cards in a single deck) and use this line of code: `int playerCard = (int) (Math.random() * 52);`. I was going to manually go through all 52 possibilities and assign each of them to an index in the array. I realized this would take too much time and effort, especially because I have to do this multiple times in this assignment. It just wouldn't be efficient if everyone did this every time they wanted to generate random numbers without repeats.

Notes:
If possible, please try not to use `import java.util.Random;`, but Scanner is ok.
Also, if this changes anything, I am to put this in a for loop.

Comment: import java.util.Randomclass has only 48 bits where as import java.security.SecureRandom; can have upto 128 bits which makes the probability of repeating in SecureRandom are smaller.Due to this also the number of attempts to break Random number prediction comes to 2^48 while that of SecureRandom number is 2^128 which again makes it more secure.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by you saying using an array would take too much time and effort. I would create a `boolean[]` of size 52 which records whether or not a card has been called. A simple check `if (array[17])` would confirm if the card has been called. The easiest way to create randomness without repeats is by storing what has already been done.

Comment: @AdrianRusso Wouldn't I have to do something like this for that to work?:
`if( playerCard == 1 )`
and set each to false/true?

Comment: My suggestion is to save this information in a boolean array, so the expressions `array[3]` and `array[3] == true` are equivalent. You would only have to change the value of one index in the array, not all. This array would last throughout your game.

Comment: How would I record which numbers have been generated in the array?
The only way I know how is to go through each number with an if statement and set it to false.

Comment: By default, every value in the array would be false. When you generate a new card, record this in the array by only changing the corresponding value in the array to true, and nothing else.

Comment: Just create an array of ints, and shuffle that array.

Comment: @NomadMaker's comment is actually the correct answer. In case it's not clear, your stated goal _"generate random numbers without duplicates"_ can be rephrased as _"given a set of unique numbers, return them shuffled in a random order"_.

Comment: Yes this answer is correct, but I'm not sure I understand what is wrong with my method for the OP's situation?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the available card (or card indexes) in a list. Then remove a random card (or index) like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(deck.size());
Card nextCard = deck.remove(randomIndex);
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to create a `boolean[]` of size 52 which records whether or not a card has been called. For example:

```
boolean[] cardCalled = new boolean[52];
```

Then, whenever you generate a new card:

```
int playerCard;
do {
    playerCard = (int) (Math.random() * 52);
} while(cardCalled[playerCard]);
cardCalled[playerCard] = true;
```

And now you have `playerCard` to work with, which is guaranteed to be a new card in the game.

To reshuffle the deck (return all cards to the deck):

```
cardCalled = new boolean[52];
```

Comment: Consider what happens when there is only one card left in the deck.  Do you really want to loop, generating random numbers, until you happen to hit the right `cardCalled` element?

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!